# Bootstrap alerts overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have modified the bootstrap alerts so they show on the top of the content without moving down any other div, but the issue i have is that the application can show at the same time warnings, errors or success messages but they are overlapping each other.

Here is my alert's css:

```
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 800px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 8px 35px 8px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Edit:** Here is the [Example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6nA9/)

**Edit 2:** Thanks to Praveen, here is the code that suits my app: [Final code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnar/Q6nA9/5/)

Comment: Please consider providing a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Done, sorry this is my first post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the position is **`absolute`**, you are facing this problem. Make them **`relative`** this way:

```
.alert {
  position: relative;
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Q6nA9/2/

Comment: I tried that but it moves down the page contents, I want to (if its possible) the content not move.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. You can wrap it up in a `div` of `absolute` position. But, is it fine if the alerts overlap your contents?

Comment: It is fine because they have the dismiss button and they also fade out after some seconds, thats why I dont want the rest of the content moving down and up again.  Im sorry im not a CSS pro, you mean wrap the alerts in another div and make it absolute?

Comment: @jnar Yes. That is what I meant.